# iOS Safari - trouble with fixed elements and bounce effect

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, mobile-safari

We are currently developing our Cordova app for iOS and there seems to be an issue with how bounce affects elements with fixed position.

There is a navigator menu fixed to the bottom of the screen. When the view is scrolled and bounce effect occurs this element either disappears for a second and reappears again, or sometime moves to the middle of the screen before returning to its original position.

Is there any way to make this element "stick" to the bottom of the screen regardless of bounce effect, preferably with pure css?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I am having this issue as well, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Ray_Poly If I remember correctly we couldn't find a solution to this and ended up not using bounce effects. I'm sorry I cannot help you.